# Search on this site doesn't return any result

Tags: 2010, search, sharepoint-server

I am build a community website under our intranet, using SharePoint 2010. I do not have access to the server, but have administration privileges.

However, when launching a search with any keyword, either through the built-in field or the search web-part, it always return 0 results.

I've tried even simple keywords like "a", to no avail. What could cause this problem ?

Comment: Also, "a" is that the full word? Or is it part of a word? If so, you should use "a*" to search for items with a word starting with "a"

Comment: Do you have access to the Central admin? then check Crawl log, and make sure full crawl completed? also make sure crawl the default zone of the web app.

Comment: I don't have any other access except for administration privileges on the site. @RobertLindgren it doesn't work even when I enter the name of an existing page (i.e. `home` or `home*` returns nothing, even though home.aspx exists). However, `a*` returns `too many results were found. Try again with more specific keywords.`

Answer (score 2):

Contact your SharePoint administrator and make sure that he performs a full crawl. Also check the site settings and make sure your site is enabled to use search.